# Use selenium for find element

Tags: python, selenium, get

I would like to take the word "buy"

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-commentaire']")

print(commentaire)
```

and i also did

```
browser.find_element_by_id("js-commentaire")

print(commentaire)
```

This the source code

```
"div class="col-6 form-control form-control-sm overflow-auto" id="js-commentaire"> buy</div"
```

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need following libs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And then try this:

```
my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='js-commentaire']")))
print(my_element.text)
```

Or

```
my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='js-commentaire']")))
print(my_element.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the possibility to print the result of the `browser.find_element()` function you need to store its result into a variable like that:

```
commentaire = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-commentaire']")
```

and then you'll be able to print it with

```
print(commentaire)
```

But this will print just the object and will be useless. To print the content of the element that's what you need to do:

```
print(commentaire.text)
```